# STL map.find returns all the elements

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, find, std

Having a problem with undefined behaviour of STL map defined as follows:

```
typedef bool (*SNAPSHOT_CALLBACK)(/*Some params here..*/);
typedef std::map<DWORD, SNAPSHOT_CALLBACK> SnapshotsMap;
SnapshotsMap m_mapCallbacks;
```

insertion:

```
AddCallback(DWORD snapshotType, SNAPSHOT_CALLBACK callback)
    m_mapCallbacks.insert(std::pair<DWORD, SNAPSHOT_CALLBACK>(snapshotType, callback));
```

and query:

```
for (auto itr = m_mapCallbacks.find(cpyHeader->hdr); itr != m_mapCallbacks.end(); itr++)
{
   itr->second();
}
```

The problem that I'm having is on a single key search the iterator retrieves both keys that I have inserted.
My logs:

```
Insert:
   Added callback type: 21000b Callback: 615F5AE0
   Added callback type: 210136 Callback: 615F5480
Query:
   Same iterator loop:
      Key to find: 21000b -> FOUND First: 21000b Second: 61da5ae0
      Key to find: 21000b -> FOUND First: 210136 Second: 61da5480
```

for some reason both elements get retrieved and there's no other modifications/thread on this map.
Some help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) only looks for a single item, so no need to iterate. Maybe you were confusing this with [`std::map::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/equal_range) ? (although that's more useful with a multimap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query should be

```
// C++17 if construct
if (auto itr = m_mapCallbacks.find(cpyHeader->hdr); itr != m_mapCallbacks.end())
{
   itr->second();
}
```

or

```
// pre-C++17 (but C++11 for auto)
auto itr = m_mapCallbacks.find(cpyHeader->hdr);
if (itr != m_mapCallbacks.end())
{
   itr->second();
}
```

Your `for` iterates from found key until the end (so only (potentially) skips first elements)

Comment: Yes that was it, I glanced at some code here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-find-function-in-c-stl/ didn't read much into it